# Short syntax for call function if defined

Tags: perl, function, shortcode, defined

is there a shorter syntax or operator for

```
defined $functionpointer ? $functionpointer->($value) : $value
```

i would like to have sth like the `//`-Operator, so that I can shortly write

```
$functionpointer //->() $value
```

or anything in that direction

what I **don't** want to do is write an extra method, overload operators or so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is none. There are discussion, though, about introducing it: [What operator should p5p use for safe dereferencing](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=973015) at PerlMonks.

Answer (score 3):

You can replace the `$functionpointer` by an anonymous constant function that returns your default value like this (tested in 5.12.1):

```
($functionpointer // sub {$default})->(@args)
```

It's a little hackish, but it works. :)

Comment: The problem with such an implementation is that it acts differently than a supposed `$ref//->(vals)` in that it actually evaluates the function arguments whereas `defined($ref) ? $ref->(vals): somethingelse`. Important if `vals` is something like an action reading from a file.

Comment: Yep, that's obviously true. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I thought about a previous `$functionpointer //= sub{@_}` as similar to your solution, but it's way slower (about 1.5 and higher) in my tests and this is nothing where I want to go to

Answer (score 2):

I think it is already pretty concise compared with most languages. I don't understand what you are hoping to achieve by making it even less legible

One thing that I would do is remove the `defined`, leaving

```
$functionpointer ? $functionpointer->($value) : $value
```

as if `$functionpointer` is defined and is a valid subroutine reference it will always be true

Comment: I like to shorten such things up because 1. i think it improves readability and 2. it removes redundancy in the code